# Delphi XE2, Intraweb 2.1.23 and cookies

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, intraweb

i did everything exactly the same as in the cookies example (shown here http://www.atozed.com/intraweb/docs/Develop/Cookies.aspx), but it's not compiling and it says "[DCC Error] Login.pas(38): E2035 Not enough actual parameters" and places the courser right after the "WebApplication.Response.Cooki­es.Add"

what am i missing?
is there a unit i need to add to the uses?

i use Delphi XE2, and Intraweb 2.1.23
oh, and i'm new to intraweb...

please help
thank you

Comment: Does the method Add doesn't show any other parameters on doing Ctrl-Shift-Space?

Comment: Intraweb 14 (XIV) is out. If you are maintaning a legacy app IW2 makes sense, if not do not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working code block that will create a Cookie in Intraweb 12.2.8  XE2

make sure that you add **IW.HTTP.Cookie** in your uses clause.

and of course you will have to modify the TiwfrmMain to match your iwform and also declare the procedure :)  via:  procedure MakeCookie;   in your

```
procedure TiwfrmMain.MakeCookie;
    var cookieMain: THttpCookie;

begin

 try
  cookieMain:=  THttpCookie.Create('email',editLogin.Text,'',Date + 999);
  WebApplication.Response.Cookies.Add(cookieMain);
  cookieMain.free;  
 except

 end;

end;
```

and you can also then get it via:

```
procedure TiwfrmMain.SetCookie;
begin
  try


    if WebApplication.Request.CookieFields.IndexOfName('email')> -1 then
    editLogin.Text := WebApplication.Request.CookieFields.Values['email'];


  except

  end;

end;
```

njoy  :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure **httpapp** is in your uses clause and try something like this:

```
procedure TIWServerController.SetCookie;
var
  mCookie: TCookie;
begin
  mCookie := WebApplication.Response.Cookies.Add;
  with mCookie do begin
    Name:='mycookie';
    Value:='mycookievalue';
    Expires := Date + 30;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score -2):

My Code:

```
procedure SetCookie(AIWApplication: TIWApplication; AName, AValue: string; AExpiration: TDate);
var
   LCookie: TCookie;
begin
   AIWApplication.Response.Cookies.Add(LCookie);
 with LCookie do
 begin
   Name := AName;
   Value := AValue;
   Expires := AExpiration;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should probably write a few lines of text to explain what you code does or how it solved the problem. As it is right now, this is considered a low quality answer.